# Is there a JavaScript project that normalizes ECMAScript 5

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Is there a JavaScript project anywhere that focuses on native normalization ECMAScript 5 in common browsers?

For reference, normalizing a table like this: http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

I know about wrappers that adds some ES5 functionality, and falls back on native implementations if they exist. But I havent seen a project that focuses solely on native implementation and normalization. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd pretty much recommend the ES5 Shim:

https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim

Comment: @c69 I recommend you use that in production, every day. It's stable, it's rock solid.

Comment: @Raynos i mean.. its unfair to even call it "ES5 shim", because it only implements Array extras, `.trim`, Date `.now` and `.toJSON`, which are fairly small subset of ES5. (small, but very useful, though).

Comment: @c69: you just cannot shim all new features. Like `.freeze()` or `.seal()` and other features can only very crappy be implemented, like `Object.create()` or `Object.defineProperties()`. However, you at least can create pollyfills for all of them so existing es5 code will not break (unless it heavily relys on the result)

Comment: @c69 ... It shims everything that can be shimmed. If you can find ways to shim more then please contribute

Comment: @Raynos: I wouldn't agree with that. Doesn it for instance just "return" the original object for `.freeze()` and `.seal()` ? That is not a shim at all, its just a polyfill.

Comment: @jAndy "shims everything that can be shimmed". If you find a way to shim freeze let us know :)

Comment: @Raynos: I already mentioned in a previous comment that this is not possible. I just did not agree on "shims everything that can be shimmed" statement. It does not "shim" some methods, but just creates them to avoid referenceerrors (more like polyfill).

Comment: @jAndy of your saying that non compliant emulations are not "shims". I meant it shims everything that can be shimmed and for the other methods it tries as hard as it can.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use polyfills for only those features of ES5 that you are actually using in your application, rather than including an extra library full of things that you'll only use some bits and pieces of.  YAGNI FTW.  It's worth noting that some features of ES5 are "unshimmable" in some browsers.

Answer (score -1):

See http://www.mascaraengine.com/ for a different approach.